# Check if a value from a table is not in other tables SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a database with more tables and I have to check if the name from a selected table is other tables.

For example, let's suppose that our database contains 4 tables(called Laptop1, Laptop2, Laptop3 and Laptop4) and every table define a laptop. So it contains Name, Date, Model. I can select table Laptop1 and I have to check if Laptop1.name doesn't exist in Laptop2, Laptop3 or Laptop4.

I'm working in SQL and the app is written in C#.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: "let's suppose that our database contains 4 tables(called Laptop1, Laptop2, Laptop3 and Laptop4)" **Let me stop you right there.** If this resembles your actual database design than you have a major flaw in your database. Instead of these four tables should only be one table for laptops, and the distinction between the different laptop types should be by a designated column in that table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXCEPT clause to get the laptop names which are not present in other tables.

```sql
SELECT Name FROM Laptop1
EXCEPT
(
SELECT Name FROM Laptop2
UNION ALL
SELECT Name FROM Laptop3
UNION ALL
SELECT Name FROM Laptop4)
```

Ideally, you should not have multiple tables holding laptop information. In relational model, Laptop is a set which holds set of laptops. You can differentiate the laptop by using unique Key called Primary Key. First define a single laptop table and load unique data. The table now holds the unique laptops information

```sql
CREATE TABLE Laptop(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, LaptopModelDate DATE NOT NULL, Model VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO Laptop(Name, LaptopModelDate,Model)
SELECT Name,Date,Model FROM Laptop1
UNION
SELECT Name,Date,Model FROM Laptop2
UNION
SELECT Name,Date,Model FROM Laptop3
UNION
SELECT Name,Date,Model FROM Laptop4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select l1.*
from laptop1 l1
where 
    not exists (select 1 from laptop2 l2 where l2.name = l1.name)
    and not exists (select 1 from laptop3 l3 where l3.name = l2.name)
    and not exists (select 1 from laptop4 l4 where l4.name = l2.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use not exists. 
But I agree with Zohar Peled : The architecture doesn't seem relevant. You should have all the laptops in the same table.
Don't forget that checking not exists is gonna cost much IO specially if using a varchar. 
If you still go this way :
- check your indexes. You will probably need an index on the name column of both tables
- sometimes using an inner join is more performant in recent versions of sql server due to the execution plan which will change even if the result is the same. It will return results which exist only in the 4 tables :

```
    select id from laptop1 l1
    Inner join laptop2 l2 on l1.name = l2.name
    Inner join...
```

--> null if name wasn't found in one table.

But still this won't be performant at all and if you could you should review the architectur

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a work project and I can't change the architecture. I will try your solution and I will tell you if it's ok for my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a real database, you should work on fixing it.  Barring that, I would recommend creating a view in the database:

```
create view v_laptops as
    select name, date, model, 1 as which from laptop1 union all
    select name, date, model, 2 from laptop2 union all
    select name, date, model, 3 from laptop3 union all
    select name, date, model, 4 from laptop4;
```

Then use the view in your queries:

```
select ot.*, l.*
from othertable ot join
     v_laptops l
     on ot.name = l.name;
```

You might want to talk to the masters of the database about fixing the data model.  Splitting information across multiple tables is usually a bad idea.

You really don't want to deal with a bunch of different tables and similar code referenced in multiple queries.  That seems like a maintenance nightmare.  Views can help isolate such design problems from users.